# Nestjs is not injecting repository dependency when testing using Test.createTestingModule

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, nestjs, vitest

I am suffering with an issue on nestjs authomatic dependecy injection that I can't resolve.
The problem is when I am running a unit test of a service, the repository is `undefined` inside the service! But when I run the service, the application works fine!

I am using vitest to run the tests and pnpm to manage the packages!
The repository, and the details to reproduce de example is on [this github](https://github.com/BrunoTerra97/nestjs-dependency-injection-issue-example)

I have a simple abstract class called `UserRepository` and two implementations, `PrismaUserRepository` for running production code that deals with a real database and `LocalUserRepository` that only implements the methods without any dependency.

```
export abstract class UserRepository {
  abstract getById(id: string): Promise<User | undefined>;
}
```

Prisma implementation:

```
@Injectable()
export class PrismaUserRepository implements UserRepository {
  constructor(private repository: RemoteRepository) {}

  async getById(id: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    const rawUser = await this.repository.rawUser.findUnique({
      where: { id },
    });

    if (rawUser) {
      return new User(rawUser);
    }
  }
}
```

Local implementation for tests:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalUserRepository implements UserRepository {
  async getById(_id: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return {} as User;
  }
}
```

My service is called `GetUserUseCase` and only depends of the `UserRepository`

```
@Injectable()
export class GetUserUseCase {
  constructor(private readonly userRepository: UserRepository) {}

  async execute({ userId }: GetUserRequest): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.getById(userId);

    if (!user) {
      throw new NotFoundException('User not found');
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

I have a controller with a Get route with a hard coded `userId` of "123" and the API is working!
[image]

The app.module is like this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: ['.env'],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [
    GetUserUseCase,
    RemoteRepository,
    { provide: UserRepository, useClass: PrismaUserRepository },
  ],
})
```

And now, the problem! My unit test is broken! The repository is not getting injected when the `GetUserUseCase` service runs

Test setup:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: UserRepository,
          useClass: LocalUserRepository,
        },
        GetUserUseCase,
      ],
    }).compile();

    userRepository = moduleRef.get<UserRepository>(UserRepository);
    spyUserRepositoryGetById = vi.spyOn(userRepository, 'getById');
    getUserUseCase = moduleRef.get<GetUserUseCase>(GetUserUseCase);
  });
```

The error:
[image]

I can make the tests run with two approachs, but I do not want to make those ways, because for my real codebase, it will make me and my team suffer a lot!

The first and easiest way to make it run, is to instanciate the service passing the `UserRepository` as a dependency:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        {
          provide: UserRepository,
          useClass: LocalUserRepository,
        },
        GetUserUseCase,
      ],
    }).compile();

    userRepository = moduleRef.get<UserRepository>(UserRepository);
    spyUserRepositoryGetById = vi.spyOn(userRepository, 'getById');
    // getUserUseCase = moduleRef.get<GetUserUseCase>(GetUserUseCase);
    getUserUseCase = new GetUserUseCase(userRepository);
  });
```

It is not good for a big codebase, because I have so many services and I will need to do this in each test

The other way to make this work is puting a injection decorator inside the service, and use the provide with it's name:
Service code:

```
@Injectable()
export class GetUserUseCase {
  constructor(
    @Inject(UserRepository.name)
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}
```

And the test file will look like this:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    providers: [
      {
        provide: UserRepository.name,
        useClass: LocalUserRepository,
      },
      GetUserUseCase,
    ],
  }).compile();

  userRepository = moduleRef.get<UserRepository>(UserRepository.name);
  spyUserRepositoryGetById = vi.spyOn(userRepository, 'getById');
  // getUserUseCase = moduleRef.get<GetUserUseCase>(GetUserUseCase);
  getUserUseCase = new GetUserUseCase(userRepository);
});
```

Note that i have put `UserRepository.name` in the `provide` and in the `moduleRef.get` parameters. And to the server runs correctly, I have to make the same in the `app.module.ts`

I have tried using `useValue` and mocked the functions instead of using `useClass` but did not work as well!

So this is what I have to show. I realy want to make the unit tests work only doing a simple configuration using `Test.createTestingModule` because doing this way the codebase will only have one big `Test.createTestingModule` with all the configuration!

Comment: Seems like vitest might be missing the swc integration to make the type metadata reflection work. [Did you follow the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swc#vitest)?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel this is exactly what I needed!
After configuring everything worked as expected!!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vitest` by default uses `esbuild` as a Typescript interpreter under the hood. This is great and fast **but** esbuild doesn't support `emitDecoratorMetadata` which Nest extensively uses to know how to inject providers into each other. To fix this, you can tell `vitest` to use `@swc/core` through a plugin, which **does** support the `emitDecoratorMetadata` option, allowing vitest to still be the test runner of choice.

[Documentation on the setup can be found in Nest's docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swc#vitest)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I was missing